# Confused about singleTop mode

Tags: android, android-activity

I've read in the android docs that singleTop mode is this:

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the
>   current task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance
>   of the activity. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each
>   instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple
>   instances (but only if the activity at the top of the back stack is
>   not an existing instance of the activity).

However, my app is behaving differently.  My main activity has the singleTop launch mode defined in the manifest file.  Here is where it's behaving oddly.

1. Start main activity from launcher.
2. From main activity, start sub activity.
3. When user presses back button (or actionbar home button), it sends intent to main activity with some extras.  This means that main activity needs to be updated (depending on the user actions in sub activity.)
4. Main activity is shown with updated display.

**-- the odd part is this --**

5. From main activity, pressing back button goes back again to main activity.
6. Pressing back button a 2nd time brings up the launcher screen, then my app is put in the background.

On step 5, why does it bring up the main activity again?  I thought singleTop will bring to front the main activity which is the current top of the stack in the task.  But from that behavior in #5 and #6, it seems like it's creating two instances of main activity instead.

Is my understanding incorrect or something else is going on that I'm not clear of yet.  Please help explain/clarify.  Thanks.

My sub activity has its onBackPressed method overridden.  And likewise, the main activity onNewIntent() handles the extras.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.UPDATE_ARG, true);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Note: If I use singleTask mode, it behaves as I expected of singleTop.  But I've read somewhere that singleTask and singleInstance are to be used sparingly.

Comment: Pressing back does not send an intent, it finishes the top activity. These are not the same thing.

Comment: @Karakuri  I forgot to mention, I've overridden the onBackpressed() method on the sub activity and created a new intent there for the main activity passing extras (if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From posted doc:

> one task can have multiple instances (but only if the activity at the
>   top of the back stack is not an existing instance of the activity).

From your code:

> When user presses back button (or actionbar home button), it sends
>   intent to main activity with some extras. This means that main
>   activity needs to be updated (depending on the user actions in sub
>   activity.)

when user presses back button your main activity dose not exist at the top of the current task and your sub activity is at the top because it has not destroyed yet, so it creates another main activity and do not use existing one because that main activity is not top.
look at this from the doc, **note that the `backstack` contains current foreground activity**:

[image]

Comment: So how do you properly implement the singleTop mode then?  I'm really confused.

Comment: you can use `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or i think you should use [startActivityForResualt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: it defeats the purpose of using singleInstance just to have singleTop mode behavior. And it doesn't make sense for me to use startActivityForResult if my sub activity doesn't return immediately.  I've encountered my app being terminated for out of memory reasons when the user stayed too long in sub activity.  When it returned to main, it hanged coz main was already cleaned up by the system.

Comment: Thanks btw, the bolded note **the backstack contains current foreground activity** helped me understand and figure out some things.

Answer (score 0):

> why does it bring up the main activity again?

Well, because you're starting your activity again when you do:

`startActivity(intent);`

Any updates in your Activity should be performed in the onStart method (or onResume if applicable).

Comment: I have my updates in the onResume.  I only grab the intent on the onNewIntent method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what is that you're trying to accomplish. I feel like you're fighting against the TaskStack when most users/apps shouldn't really have to worry about it. I'd try to approach the problem from a different angle (like start activity for result or having a common storage where Activity A can load its data from and where Activity B can save data). If what you're trying to do feels hacky, then it probably is. :)

Comment: I just want to implement the singleTop mode where I don't need to reistantiate the main activity, but reuse an existing main activity from the backstack and bring it to top.  My main activity display a lot of data fetched from an sqlite database, and reinstantiating it will go through all that again, whereas reusing and updating the existing one has very little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally made sense out of all this (I think!).  I'll explain.

`android:launchMode` attribute applies to the activity whether it's started from home launcher, from within your app (or from another app).

The intent flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is needed to implement the `singleTop` behavior.  Therefore, I passed that flag when creating the intent prior to starting the activity.

For the main activity, here's what I did:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    // these flags are important!!
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.UPDATE_ARG, true);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And correspondingly, I declared `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest file.

Comment: "`android:launchMode` attribute only applies if your app's main activity is being launched from home launcher (or from another app)." **sorry but your conclusion is not true at all**! another things i must say is when you use `launchMode` and `Intent flag`, `Intent flag` wins and overwrites `launchMode` but if you do not specify intent flag system look at the `launchMod`

Comment: Can you please show me when my conclusion is wrong?  It's what I've understood so far, I don't know of other use cases where it contradicts my conclusion for now.

Comment: @mmlooloo Okay, I got curious and tried to test something else and you're right.  `launchMode` does affect how the activity is started even from within your own app.  I'll edit my post to reflect the corrections.